# Parse a table with PHP and Xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I would to get informations from this table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="1">Monday</th>
            <td colspan="3" class="closed">Closed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sep"></tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Tuesday</th>
            <td>12:30 pm</td>
            <td class="sep">-</td>
            <td>2:00 pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7:30 pm</td>
            <td class="sep">-</td>
            <td>10:00 pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="sep"></tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Wednesday</th>
            <td>12:30 pm</td>
            <td class="sep">-</td>
            <td>2:00 pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7:30 pm</td>
            <td class="sep">-</td>
            <td>10:00 pm</td>
        </tr>
        ...
        <tr class="sep"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using this to get the hours with PHP and Xpath:

```
$h = 0;
preg_match_all('/<table.*?>(.*?)<\/table>/is', $page, $hours);
$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($hours[0][0]); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if($row->getAttribute('class') == 'sep') {}
    else {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

        if($cols->item(0)->nodeValue == 'Closed') {
            $datas[$activity]['hours']['day'.$h] = 'Closed';
        }
        else {
            $datas[$activity]['hours']['day'.$h]['open'] = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue;
            $datas[$activity]['hours']['day'.$h]['close'] = $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
        }
        $h++;
    }
}
```

The problem is for day like Tuesday I have two sets of hours (noon and evening). My code is working but separate the datas in two.

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting, for Tuesday, I want to be able to extract `12:30 pm - 2:00 pm` and `7:30 pm - 10:00 pm`.

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that php doesn's support xpath 2.0 and above, so we have to resort to trickery using xpath 1.0. You can start with this and modify it to your needs:

```
$days = $xp->query('//tr/th');

foreach ($days as $day) {
    $target = $day->textContent;
    echo $target . "\r\n";
    $exp = '//tr/th[./text()="' .$target . '"]//following-sibling::td[not(@class="sep")]';
    $exp2 = '//tr[th[./text()="' .$target . '"]]//following-sibling::tr[not(./th)][1]//td[not(@class="sep")]';
    $hours = $xp->query($exp);
    $hours2 = $xp->query($exp2);
    myFunction($hours);
    myFunction($hours2);

 echo "\r\n";
}

function myFunction($somethings){
    foreach($somethings as $something){
        $info = $something->textContent;
        echo $info . "\r\n";

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Monday
Closed 

Tuesday
12:30 pm 
2:00 pm 
7:30 pm 
10:00 pm 

Wednesday
12:30 pm 
2:00 pm 
7:30 pm 
10:00 pm
```